# How to setup stackdriver for the RAM usage in google compute engine?

Tags: google-compute-engine, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

i have created an instance on compute engine, now i want to know how we can setup stack driver to check RAM usage, CPU utilization and number of users interacting with the instance

Answer (score 2):

To be able to monitor the RAM usage and CPU you need to install the Stackdriver Agent on your instance. The process will change depending on the OS you are using, here is the reference for [Linux](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/install-agent#linux-install):

```
curl -sSO https://dl.google.com/cloudagents/install-monitoring-agent.sh
sudo bash install-monitoring-agent.sh
```

And for [Windows](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/install-agent#windows-install) through Powershell:

```
cd C:\Users\[USERNAME]
invoke-webrequest https://repo.stackdriver.com/windows/StackdriverMonitoring-GCM-46.exe -OutFile StackdriverMonitoring-GCM-46.exe;
.\StackdriverMonitoring-GCM-46.exe
```

[Here is a list](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-compute) of the available metrics for Compute Engine once the agent is installed, but I don't think the number of users logged in is one of them.